# Organic Chemistry: Numeric prefix for 9 carbons doesn't follow pattern of greek numbers

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

In the nomenclature of organic compounds, a numeric prefix is used for denoting the number of carbon atoms in the main structure. From "pent" onwards, they seem to follow a pattern of greek numerals, however, at 9 carbons, there is an exception: "non" instead of "ene". Why is that? Is it to avoid confusion with double bond insaturations, like *"eneene"* would create? Is it just to make it sound better?

PS: Forgive my lack of knowledge on the subject, I only recently got an introduction to organic chemistry.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: In [this answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/96000/17175) we find that in fact it is the Latin prefixes which were original. The Greek prefixes are the intruders, except for nine. I still favor "enneagon" for the polygon, though.

Comment: Yeah, it does, Oscar had sent the same thing earlier. Thanks :D

Comment: Naming conventions are a hodgepodge, e.g., methanol, from Greek "μέθυ + ὕλη", i.e., "wine + wood", ethanol, directly from "μέθυ ", propionic acid, from "πρῶτος + πίων", "first fat". And methanoic acid is known as *formic* acid, because it made by ants, and ethanoic acid is *acetic* acid is from vinegar in Latin, *acetum*.  Hope you don't mind taking up your thyme (θυμώνω, which is sour??) with etymology.